# Focus the cloned element

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a `ng-template` that will be cloned whenever a button is clicked. In `ng-template` there is a input field that has the attribute `autofocus`. What I want is to focus that input field that will be cloned. How can I do it?

I have tried it with `this.email.nativeElement.focus();` but I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

**HTML:**

```
<form id="add-user">
    <ng-template #emailTmpl>
        <mat-form-field class="email full-width">
            <input autofocus #email matInput class="email-field" type="email" required placeholder="E-Mail">
        </mat-form-field>
    </ng-template>
    <div #furtherEmails></div>
</form>
<i class="material-icons icon" id="addEmailField" (click)="clone()">add_box</i>

<button mat-raised-button class="full-width" color="primary">Invite</button>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.sass']
})

export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('emailTmpl') emailTmpl;
    @ViewChild('email') email;
    @ViewChild('furtherEmails', {read: ViewContainerRef}) furtherEmails;

    public clone(): void {
        this.furtherEmails.createEmbeddedView(this.emailTmpl);
        this.email.nativeElement.focus();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.clone();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be notified that a new `input` element was created by subscribing to the `QueryList.changes` event, where the `QueryList<ElementRef>` is obtained with `ViewChildren`. Every time the event is triggered, you can then focus the last element of the list. See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c6lrvf) for a demo.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
...

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('emailTmpl') emailTmpl;
  @ViewChild('furtherEmails', { read: ViewContainerRef }) furtherEmails;
  @ViewChildren('email') email: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  public clone(): void {
    this.furtherEmails.createEmbeddedView(this.emailTmpl);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.email.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.email.last.nativeElement.focus();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the error "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined". You can test it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-clone-y7xxoc?file=app/issue-list/issue-list.component.ts

Comment: You should use `ViewChildren` to get the `QueryList`, not `ViewChild`.

Comment: Oh I see, it works great now but now I get the error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: false'. Current value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: true'.

Comment: You can call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` after cloning the element to eliminate the exception. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-clone-mmmawm).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, a `ViewChild` property cannot be accessed until the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook. Try implementing AfterViewInit and adding your focus statement there.

The elements are not yet created at the time of the ngOnInit so the nativeElement is null yet at that point.

Here is some sample code from one of my applications:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-criteria',
  templateUrl: './criteria.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./criteria.component.css']
})
export class CriteriaComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('filterElement') filterElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.filterElementRef.nativeElement) {
      this.filterElementRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Deborah!